# About それも usage

Tags: grammar

> 2008年までは輸入はともかく輸出はアメリカが一番だったんですが、それも中国で。

The part made me confused is the latter one, "それも中国で". Does it mean "That is also true in China" or something else because it doesn't sound right to me and I hope someone can clear my doubt. Thank you.

For more information, this is a news about Japanese export and import value and the context leads to that sentence about China has beaten America and became the country with highest import and export value to Japan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence can be rephrased as...

> 2008年までは輸入はともかく輸出はアメリカが一番だったんですが、それも**今は**中国で。

(今は is not there but is implied in the original)

The それ is a normal pronoun, "it/that". It refers to 輸出 here.「それも中国で」 means 「輸出の一番も今は中国で」 or 「輸出も今は中国が一番で」, "As for the highest export value, it is also China now (as well as import value)."

Comment: Oh, I get it. However, I got another question if you don't mind.
About で in the end, so it has the same function as "です" right?

Comment: @elPsyChris The sentence 「～～で。」 can be information added/supplemented to the previous sentence, like... 「輸入は中国が一番です。輸出は以前はアメリカが一番だったんですが、それも今は中国で。」 (「～～で。」 can also be used for giving a reason. eg 「宿題できませんでした。母が病気で‥。」)